# ImagePicker using Video. Odd Compiler Error

Tags: iphone, video

I have been trying to get video to work and have been getting an odd issue with a compiler issue. My code looks like this.

```
 UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePicker.sourceType];

    imagePicker.sourceType  = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    [imagePicker release];
```

The compiler Error I am getting says:

> Undefined symbols:   "_kUTTypeMovie",
>   referenced from:
>         _kUTTypeMovie$non_lazy_ptr in EditViewController.o
>        (maybe you meant: _kUTTypeMovie$non_lazy_ptr) ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

I have been working at this for a while and can't figure out where my issue is.  I have imported Core Services so I have access to kUTTypeMovie.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

have you tried a call to availableMediaTypesForSourceType: for testing the camera ?

Problem sloved through adding the MobileCoreServices framework and importing it with #import  accordingly.

Comment: yes, I did. if I comment out the line with kUTTypeMovie I get no compiler error.

Comment: With #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h> and the according Framework added, i get no compiler errors.

Comment: Forgot to add the framework.  Thank you!  Could you please include that in your original answer and I will mark it as the best answer for this question.

Comment: i got problem of compressing video can you help me to solve it